# pagination broken on custom theme's search system page

Tags: 7, search, paging

I do not have pagination on the system search page .../search*.

When I toggle off my custom theme I have pagination on the search-result.tpl.php page, I can see the `$pager` variable. But on my custom theme I cannot find that variable, it doesn't show up. I have checked hook_query_alter() throughout all of my site and I do not see any conflict. I checked the template.php file and there is no issue there. I will begin to remove everything, piece by piece to find out if I can find a solution.

No real code to show, and I would send you a stock search-results.tpl.php page, but the code block doesn't want to show it because `<?php ?>` is interspersed with html tags. It is something like:

```
if ($search_results) {  print t('search results');   print $pager; }
```

I simplified it because of the aformentioned issue, but this is essentially it - it is so minimal it is laughable and it works for any other theme, but mine. So I just copy the search-results.tpl.php file over to bartik, then do `drush cc -v all` and recheck and I can use xdebugger to see the `$pager` variable, but the same file with my custom theme I never get the `$pager` variable.

Comment: So what exactly do you expect from us? Without code, or specific question there is not much for us to help with :)

Answer (score 0):

So i found out that a view on the search page had pagination and it caused a conflict with the search results pagination! I removed pagination in the View's configuration screen.

[image]

Removed the pagination of the pager settings.